# How to get a ChannelManager from within a Component

Tags: hippocms

I'm looking for a way to fetch a ChannelManager ref from within a Component#doBeforeRender call, in a somewhat similar way to the QueryManager.

Is there a *Manager registry I can ask for service interfaces?

Best,
Edoardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to ChannelManager and find usages of it. It will give you enough hits..like:

```
public static ChannelManager getChannelManager() {
    ComponentManager componentManager = HstServices.getComponentManager();
    if (componentManager == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return HstServices.getComponentManager().getComponent(ChannelManager.class.getName());
```

}

Comment: above code can be found within :org.onehippo.cms7.channelmanager.channels.ChannelUtil

Comment: change search scope from "Project" to "Project and libraries"..assuming you are using Intellij IDE